# What is the meaning of $k_B T$? is there a maximum for it?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature, material-science

What is the meaning of $k_B T$? in physics, where $k_B$ is Boltzmann constant? Is there a maximum for it? Can you give a maximum or minimum value for it among all the material? Or is there any typical value for this?

Comment: A quote from a student assignment work at pre-MIPT school: "...$\frac{1}{2}kT$ is the average energy of molecular vibration, where $k$ is the effective spring constant of the bond and $T$ is the vibration period" (folklore).

Answer (score 3):

$kT$ is an estimate of the energy that a system has due to its temperature being $T$, or given to it when its environment is at temperature $T$.

It has an obvious minimum (zero), but its maximum value is typically limited by practical factors (like the system being destroyed if temperature becomes too high, or the theory stepping outside its validity domain).

The only absolute maximum that can be mentioned is Planck energy, which also yields a temperature value. But what happens at this point is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

assuming T means temperature, I think not for $K_b T$ is an increasing function.

However, this post here [on the highest possible temperature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420670/what-is-highest-possible-temperature) suggests a limit, which is $1.4168331(85)×10^{32} J$